# Conditional Comment not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, conditional-statements, conditional-comments

I put this code into my `<head>` in order to load an additional stylesheet for IE8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-ie.css">

<![endif]-->
```

I also already did this 1000 times, but this time however it is not working. It's just not loaded in IE8. If I remove the conditional comment it load's normally.

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, since you're targeting IE8, you should keep in the type="text/css" bit which was no longer necessary in HTML5? i.e.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-ie.css" type="text/css">
```

Is this for an HTML5 site or XHTML / HTML4? If it's for an HTML5 site, following is what I usually do for these cases, as it's a good idea to also add the HTML5 shim bit in the same conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <link href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Hope this helps!